# It is not displaying any results in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
q.QuestionMarks
FROM Answer an 
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
```

My query above is displaying an empty set of results even though it should display some results. It is suppose to display each distinct question (What I mean by this is that it should distinctly display rows so that there are no duplicate rows that contains exactly the same data across all columns) Can anyone fix the query so it outputs the results it should output? Below are the tables:

Session Table:

```
SessionId  SessonName
3          ANDES
```

Question Table:

```
QuestionId  SessionId   QuestionNo  QuestionContent       NoofAnswers   ReplyId     QuestionMarks   OptionId
1           3           1           What is 2+2?          1                 1           5               2
2           3           2           What is 2+2?          1                 1           5               2
3           3           3           Name these 2 flowers  2                 2           5               4
```

Answer Table:

```
AnswerId (Auto)  QuestionId  Answer
1                1           A
2                1           B
3                2           A
4                2           D
5                3           C
```

Reply Table:

```
ReplyId  ReplyType
1        Single
2        Multiple
```

Option Table:

```
OptionId OptionType
1        A-C
2        A-D
3        A-E
4        A-F
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1881090/user1881090 http://stackoverflow.com/users/1930247/user1930247 http://stackoverflow.com/users/1808066/manixman - who are all these users with the same question? Is it some exam in some classes or what?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well my question is for an application i am bulding for a project I am doing at university. I have a partner who is on the same project who I know is on SO. I don't know about the the other one though

Comment: The other one is copying your project...[Plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism)... o.O`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered your query slightly and I am getting results.  First, I changed to use a `LEFT JOIN`, then you will get questions returned if there is no answer, etc in the additional tables.  Second, since you are using a aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT()`, you need to use a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  q.QuestionContent, 
  o.OptionType, 
  q.NoofAnswers, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, 
  r.ReplyType, 
  q.QuestionMarks
FROM Question q
LEFT JOIN Answer an
  ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
LEFT JOIN Reply r 
  ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
LEFT JOIN Option_Table o 
  ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
group by q.QuestionContent
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bb52/12)

This returns the result:

```
|      QUESTIONCONTENT | OPTIONTYPE | NOOFANSWERS | ANSWER | REPLYTYPE | QUESTIONMARKS |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Name these 2 flowers |        A-F |           2 |      C |  Multiple |             5 |
|         What is 2+2? |        A-D |           1 |    ABD |    Single |             5 |
```

Comment: . . The problem is the `group_concat` without a `group by`.  You should elaborate on why this causes this problem.